# Independence of the following statistics

Tags: statistics, education, computational-mathematics, independence

I need help with the following:

So, in my statistics class, I have covered that if $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent NORMAL variables, then $X_1$ and $X_1 - \bar X$ would be independent.

What if the variables $X_1$ to  $X_n$ are not from the normal distribution, but still are independent, are the two above statistics still independent?

Comment: I think you intended to compare $\bar X$ and $X_i - \bar X.$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Showing that $\bar X$ and the deviation $X_1 - \bar X$ are
uncorrelated is a simple exercise. But uncorrelated implies
independent only for normal data. [This result can be used
to show that the sample mean and SD are independent for normal data.]

Below is an illustration that may help you visualize the
distinction. The first plot of the deviation against the mean is
for normal data and the second is for exponential data.
About 9000 samples of size 10 are plotted in each graph.

[image]

Comment: I believe in order for uncorrelatedness to imply independence, two random variables have to be *jointly* normal. 
We know that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid normal and therefore jointly normal. Does this imply that $X_1$ and $X_1-\overline X$ are jointly normal? (I apologize if this is obvious)